# Questions about NSError in swift

Tags: swift

How do you assign an error code to an NSError in Swift? The following gives a compilation error saying "cannot assign to 'code' in 'e'":

```
        var e = NSError()
        e.code = 6;
```

Also why does the following code generate an error of 'Int is not convertible to selector'

```
        if e.code == EKAuthorizationStatus.Restricted
        {
        }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error code property is read only and of type Int. You need to initialize as follows:

```
 var e= NSError(domain: <string?>, code: 6, userInfo: <AnyObject>)
```

Update:
As @ahruss pointed out you also need to convert the enum to its raw form, since the type conversion is not implicit, I have updated the example accordingly.

Please find the documentation on NSError class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSError_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSError/code).

Example playground:

```
import Cocoa
var e = NSError(domain: nil, code: 6, userInfo: nil);

//if e.code == 6
if e.code == EKAuthorizationStatus.Restricted.toRaw()
{
    println("success");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other half of the answer ([wbennet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25192026/1325329) covered the other part, that code is readonly) is that EKAuthoriziationStatus is an enum, and you don't get implicit conversions in Swift. You need to do this:

```
if e.code == EKAuthorizationStatus.Restricted.toRaw()
{
    ...
}
```